# JS/AJAX Content Not loading when URL is accessed using Selenium(Python)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this URL: https://www.wheel-size.com/size/acura/mdx/2001/

The values that I want to scrape are loaded dynamically e.g Center Bore
If you open the link in normal browser the content is loaded just fine but if I use Selenium(chromedriver) it just keeps loading and the values are never displayed.

Any idea how can I scrape it?
Below is the picture of how it looks like. You can also see the loading for 1-2 seconds when you open the link in normal browser.

[image: screenshot of chromedriver]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the desired texts e.g. ***64.1 mm***, ***5x114.3*** etc as the elements are [Google Tag Manager](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/datalayer) enabled elements you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.wheel-size.com/size/acura/mdx/2001/')
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Center Bore')]//following::span[1]"))).text)
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'PCD')]//following::span[1]"))).text)
```

Console Output:

```
64.1 mm
5x114.3
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this approach and your code as well but I get empty strings in the console. The issue is the values are never displayed on web when I visit via selenium driver. It just keeps loading as shown in picture of my post. Could you confirm if you got the values in console?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Damn it worked <3 Thanks a lot! What are those parameters that you added in the options? I'm grateful for your help.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan Avoiding [ChromeDriver initiated _Chrome Browser_ geting detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/7429447)